# YouTube API won't load another player after getting destroyed

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, vimeo

I've checked the previous posts but couldn't find a similar issue that I'm having atm.

I'm trying to use two different APIs (Vimeo and YouTube) to embed videos. The video order is not following a provider structure. And there's going to be an autoplay function as well. For example 2 video plays from YouTube and then a vimeo plays then YouTube etc etc. Could be triggered by clicking a next button or it loads the next when the current video finishes.

Figuring out Vimeo's api wasn't that bad it was simple 1 liner codes but I really got stuck with YouTube.

The problem is I can't load another YouTube video after the first one. It only works for the first video if it's loaded on page load.

Also weirdly if I try to load another video with this code the I'm getting a console error saying that

```
TypeError: this.f is null    www-widgetapi.js:362:22
```

This isn't something I've embedded, probably coming from YT API.

Here are the snippets of the code that I'm trying to build.

I've also tried to call the `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` using the `window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function(){}` but again I get the same result.

```
// Global Variables
let ytPlayer, vmPlayer // player wrappers
let playingNow // array with provider(YT/VM), ID and a genre string
let upNext // similar array with the upcoming video

// == Player Destroyer == 
function destroyer() {
    if (playingNow.provider === 'YT' ) {
        // destroy YT
        ytPlayer.destroy()
    } else if (playingNow.provider === 'VM') {
            vimPlayer.destroy().then(function() {
                // the player was destroyed
            }).catch(function(error) {
                // an error occurred
            });
        }
}

// == PlayerCreator ==
function playerCreator(provider, id, genre) {

    // 1. Load the matching provider api player loader

    if (provider === 'YT') {

        // Create YT Player

        onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function(){
            ytPlayer = new YT.Player('propWrap', {
              videoId: id,
              events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady
              }
            });
          }

        playingNow = upNext;
        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.playVideo();
        }

        playingNow = upNext;
        return console.log(`loaded ${id} for ${provider} have some ${genre}`)

    } else if ( provider === 'VM' ) {

        // Create VM Player
        let options = {
            id: id,
            }
        vimPlayer = new Vimeo.Player('propWrap', options);
        playingNow = upNext;
        return console.log(`loaded ${id} for ${provider} have some ${genre}`)

    } else {
        console.log(`you failed at something`)
    }

    // 3. figure out how to implement autoplay
};
```

Sorry if all these looks a bit messy. Let me know if you'd like see some other parts of the code (or it doesn't makes sense)

Answer (score 0):

So I've made a progress and I'm not sure what's the logic behind it. I've added a `function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){};` globally at the top of the script doc and removed onYoutubeIFrameAPIReady function within the player creator. So if the first video is vimeo, I can destroy and recreate and player in any order. But if the first video that I'm loading I get an error saying that `YT.Player is not a constructor`